# Unable to access Short Throw ToF Reflectivity camera stream in unity il2cpp backend

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, il2cpp

I am working with the HoloLens 1 and am able to access the Short Throw ToF Reflectivity stream in UWP, but when i perform the same calls in unity i get the error `Exception thrown at 0x775D6452 (KernelBase.dll) in ArUcoDetectionHoloLensUnity.exe: WinRT originate error - 0xC00DABE0 : 'No capture devices are available.'.`
I think this may be a limitation of the il2cpp backend due to this forum post https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/13475/no-capture-devices-are-available-on-hololens-when-taking-a-picture but i haven't found much else on the internet about it. I've nearly given up on trying to pursue accessing this stream in Unity but am interested if anyone can explain why this doesn't seem to work? I am considering having a UWP process access the stream and then send the relevant data from the frame to Unity over an IPC socket. Is this viable?

Comment: May I ask does this issue occur when you deploy the app to HoloLens 1?

Comment: Yes this is on the hololens 1. I've found that it actually can still access the sensors after receiving this error, oddly enough.

Comment: What's the Unity version? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20194-lts, please make sure you are using Unity 2019.4 LTS.